how can i add chart to toolbox visual studio 2022?
in vs code 2002  i dont fint chart
i  searched on internet  but  i  did not  fint  any answer! how can  i  to  add this   to  tool  box.
I'm working on a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2022 and need to add chart controls to my toolbox. I've been searching for a way to include the chart controls but haven't found a clear step-by-step guide. Could anyone provide detailed instructions on how to do this?

To add a chart control to the toolbox in Visual Studio 2022, please follow these steps:
In the toolbox, right-click and select Choose Items…. In the Choose Toolbox Items dialog box, select the .NET Framework Components tab. Scroll through the list and find the item named "Chart" under the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting namespace. Check the box next to the Chart control and click OK.
Please note that the Chart control is a .NET Framework control and will not be supported if your project is targeting .Net Core.

In Visual Studio 2022, while working on Windows application with Target OS under Solution properties . NET 7.0. In Toolbox --> Chart is displaying as per the items add from the . NET Components tab under choose items.
enter link description here
